# What is sentential relative clauses? "which the prime minister asserted was as much as 70 percent more transmissible than previous versions"

Tags: relative-clauses

> The decision, which Mr.Johnson announced after an emergency meeting of his cabinet,came after the government got new evidence of a variant first detected several weeks ago in Southeast England, *which the prime minister asserted was as much as 70 percent more transmissible than previous versions.*

Is this sentence which I highlighted sentential relative clause? I read this sentence in The New York Times. *which the prime minister asserted was as much as 70 percent more transmissible than previous versions*

Answer (score 0):

That clause

> which the prime minister asserted was as much as 70 percent more transmissible than previous versions.

refers to "a variant", meaning a new mutation of the covid virus.

Comment: Sir,it is not refering to the whole sentence. Is this clause sentential relative clause?

Comment: No. It has a clear noun antecedent, "variant". See   https://www.grammaring.com/sentential-relative-clause